# Thorntail service with CXF executed differently when using Maven goal

Tags: maven, thorntail

I have a Thorntail v2.3.0 microservice which contains a CXF client, generated from a WSDL. I have two methods of starting the service from the command line either with Maven 3.5.3:

```
mvn clean install thorntail:run
```

Or directly with the JVM 1.8.0:

```
mvn clean install
java -jar target/myservice-thorntail.jar
```

I would expect the process to execute in the same way using both methods. However using the first method, I get the below error calling my CXF client. The error does not occur when executing it via the Java command.

```
WARN  [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader] (Thread-79) Could not load 
    or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) 
    Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: null
WARN  [org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.WSSecurityPolicyLoader] (Thread-79) Could not load 
    or register WS-SecurityPolicy related classes. Please check that (the correct version of) 
    Apache WSS4J is on the classpath: Could not initialize class org.apache.wss4j.stax.setup.WSSec
WARN  [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl] (Thread-79) No assertion builder for type 
    {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}HttpToken registered.
ERROR [stderr] (Thread-79) Exception in thread "Thread-79" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 
    None of the policy alternatives can be satisfied.
```

I've tried adding dependencies to WSS4J as suggested in the warning without effect. My POM contains these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>apache-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

My assumption is it's dependency related, but I'm not sure where to start looking for the solution. I'd prefer to execute with the first command as I can override configuration values when required.

How do I trace and diagnose the cause of this problem?

Comment: There are different classloading constructions for the two use cases.

"java -jar" will always have the more accurate classloading. Unfortunately if there is a classloading issue only in "mvn thorntail:run", then it's 99% because of a classloading issue

Comment: Thanks @Ken I'm guessing there is nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: There's a system property you can use to enable the uberjar mode: `mvn thorntail:run -Dthorntail.useUberJar`.

Comment: Thanks - that solves my problem.